# Error while loading shared library: libconfig++.so.9

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

While I compile the code in Makefile, I've put LINKPATH = -L/usr/local/lib in the g++ line. And of course "libconfig++.so.9" is under /usr/local/lib

But when I execute the executable file, it still says cannot find libconfig++.so.9.

Anyone knows why?? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

You should define LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
For example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 5):

or just use

> sudo ldconfig -v

Comment: ln -s /usr/local/lib/libdshconfig.so /lib64/libdshconfig.so.1
you can create the link also.